# Run the older, CadSoft (pre-Autodesk) version of EAGLE on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, packages, cad, ubuntu-18.04

I last ran EAGLE on Ubuntu 14, but after upgrading to Ubuntu 18, I can't find it.

This is the command I used:

```
sudo apt search eagle
```

I tried to find a PPA, but only found this one:

https://launchpad.net/~torik-habib/+archive/ubuntu/multimedia

It has no release file.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Autodesk (actually probably CadSoft, and just never *removed* by Autodesk) has provided a [FTP site](ftp://ftp.cadsoft.de/eagle/program/) where older versions of EAGLE can be downloaded from.

[source](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/eagle/troubleshooting/caas/discussion/t5/EAGLE-Forum/Download-Eagle-7/td-p/6861599.html)